# How we can move azure environment website in live environment from dev environment

Tags: azure

We are working on site in windows azure environment and about to complete the dev stuff. We want to move the website to live domain. Please suggest and guide us how we can move the development environment website to live server in azure?

Thanks,

Rahul K

Comment: are you talking about moving from a local environment (e.g. Compute Emulator and Storage Emulator) to Azure, or from one Azure state (Staging) to another (Production)?

Comment: @David thanks, yes we have a underdevelopment site in staging (Azure environment) and want to move it to live environment in Azure with actual domain name.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at this guide to get started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460772.aspx

Comment: thanks for sharing the link, will look into that and get back to you soon.